# Spirits and heaven

Tags: theravada, merit, animals, heavens

My two pet cats recently died in my rental house. Long story short, we sold our old home but we have no where to move yet so we rented a property while our new house is being built. Before I ask my questions I want to thank you guys for taking your time to reading this post . **How can I ensure that my cat spirits go to heaven?** or **How can I bring their spirits to my new home?** I am scared that they will be alone since the current rental price isn't cheap and I am scared that they will wait for me in this house. I just want them to reach heaven. **Can animal spirits go to buddhist heaven?**
I am a Theravada buddhist. Also , I am scared that there might be other spirits inside this house, I rarely don't believe in spirits but the rental house is kind of mystery itself. I am scared that those spirits might take my cat, I wish to buddha everyday that their spirits be safe and including hindu gods. **How can I make merits to my cats spirit?** **How can I know if they got the merit?** **How can I transfer the merit to them so they may reach heaven?  Are animal spirits allowed to enter heaven?**

Answer (score 1):

From a Theravada Buddhist perspective you're cats have already been reborn another place - impossible to say where unless one is a Buddha.

Try to be mindful of the wanting for them to be reborn in Heaven - the wanting/craving is what can/will cause suffering for you. You're cats own Kamma decides where they get reborn. You did your best to take care of them and love them. Be happy about that and take good care of yourself and your mind.

You can share the merits you've earned from performing [*The 10 Meritorious Deeds (one of them is meditation practice)*](http://www.suttas.com/10-meritorious-deeds.html). You could choose to share the merits with all beings in the universe and by doing that your cats will recieve it too.